# Style ul and li

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style some unordered lists and running into problems...it isn't affecting the output!

The example I can't get to change.

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="foot-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">site map</a></li>
            <li>three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#footer #foot-nav ul.blah {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#footer #foot-nav ul.blah li.blah {
    padding:2px 0;  
}

#footer #foot-nav ul.blah li.blah a {
    color:#333;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#footer #foot-nav ul.blah li.blah a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Another UL from the same page

```
.mobile-menu #mobile-menu-links ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    padding-left:3%;
}

.mobile-menu #mobile-menu-links ul li{
   padding-bottom:2px;
   border-bottom:1px solid #bababa;
}

<div class="mobile-menu" id="mobile-account">
    <div id="mobile-menu-links">
        <h4>General:</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">View your profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Change your settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="">View your messages</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The rules from the #mobile-menu ul is taking preference with the ul from the top of the question?

I'm obviously doing something wrong, could you help? Thanks!

Comment: Where's your `footer` parent?  Does it exist in the HTML?

Comment: Is everything in the #footer ? You should make a fiddle to make it clearer.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Using the class 'blah' for `ul` and `li` is a bit confusing maybe.

Comment: They have to be wrapped by an element with id `footer` is that it? http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/KpkEs/1

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the footer wrapper. It is in there though.

Comment: Don't post incomplete code.  Update your question to include the footer wrapper, it's the most obvious suspect for this problem.

Comment: There's really no reason to use descendent selectors when you're using IDs (e.g. #footer #foot-nav).  Each ID should be unique, so #foot-nav should be sufficient, unless you've re-used the ID elsewhere, which is invalid and will result in lots of weird issues.  Because the ID is unique, you could then get rid of the `blah` class, unless you plan on having multiple lists within your foot-nav.

Comment: @ernie, that's not true.  Remember, stylesheets can be applied to multiple pages and in different circumstances.  If you have `#foo` that is contained by `#bar` on one page and `#baz` on another, then you can legitimately style them differently by using this method.  It's not invalid, just uncommon.

Comment: @ernie - I didn't initially use any classes on the ul or li and I was finding it was using a declaration from elsewhere in the CSS.

Comment: @Jim Hence the "there's really no reason" caveat - yes you can come up with use cases where you may have selectors like that, but I think most people would say that's pretty convoluted, and not a best practice

Comment: I've updated the question to be more accurate, sorry for the rubbish initial amount of information!

Comment: @Luke do you have any other UL/LI CSS declarations?  Your question is changing so much, it might be better to post the full HTML and all CSS involved.

Comment: @ernie, no "there's really no reason" is wrong, and saying that it's not a best practice is misleading.  There is absolutely nothing wrong with that practice.  It's just uncommon to need it, that's all.  Don't mistake unfamiliar with bad.

Comment: @ernie the question now has the full ul/li css declarations.

Comment: @jim I think we'll have to agree to disagree.  Using IDs in different contexts in different pages breaks the whole idea of keeping things consistent.  Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should (or that it's a good idea).

Comment: @ernie, "There's no reason" and "It's not best practice" are different to "I don't want to do it because..."

Comment: @Jim so you don't think the "really" in "there's really no reason" doesn't make it clear that I'm not saying "never do this", and "it's not best practice" is also too absolute.  Fair enough.  I'd go back and edit to add some more weasel words, and make it a bit more of a suggestion if I could based on your suggestions, but the edit time window's closed on me . . .

Comment: @ernie, you can't fix those statements by adding weasel words.  The problem was not that they were absolute, it was that they are incorrect.  You saw something *unfamiliar*, and you labelled it *bad*.  That's not the kind of statement that can be fixed.

Comment: @Jim Okay, I'll admit I'm at a loss then, and don't understand how the statements were wrong.  I think "there's really no reason" is saying that "there's not many cases for this", and stating it's not best practice means that you won't find many css users doing this?  Are you stating the statements assert something else?

Comment: @ernie, *"there's really no reason"* means *"this is unnecessary"*, not *"this is uncommon"*, so it carries with it the implication *"You should not do this"*, which harms people when they come across a situation where it makes sense to do this, and they have been told otherwise.

Comment: @ernie,  *"It's not best practice"* is correct in the *literal* sense, but most practices are not best practices but nevertheless the best option - best practice is for when there is a commonly agreed upon superior method.  In the way that you used it, the only interpretation that makes sense is that you meant "best practice" as synonymous with *"the way you should do things"* (a common misconception), which means *"not the way you should do things"*, which again means *"you should not do this"*.

Comment: @ernie, in actual fact, there are plenty of times in which this is an entirely sensible thing to do, and you shouldn't warn people away from it in the general sense as it is not intrinsically bad - it is just a practice that may be applied in wrong circumstances, just like any other practice.

Comment: @Jim Thanks for the clarification.  I'm not sure I agree 100%, but I think I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#footer #foot-nav ul.blah
```

This selector applies to `<ul>` elements that have the `blah` class, which is a descendant of an element with an ID of `foot-nav`, which is a descendant of an element with an ID of `footer`.

Aside from the last part, your HTML matches that, so I would assume that the problem is that your `#foot-nav` element is not within an element with an ID of `footer`.

You can either remove `#footer` from all your selectors, or you can put your `#foot-nav` element within  an element that has an ID of `footer`.

**Edit:**

Okay, in light of the changes to the question, either there's something wrong with the CSS that is stopping it from getting applied at all, or the CSS is being overridden.

Inspect the element in a web browser's developer tools to see if the rules are showing up at all.  If they are, then they are probably being overridden by rules elsewhere on the page.  If that is the case, then you should be able to see where the other rules are while you are inspecting the element.

If the rules are not being applied at all, then it's likely there's something wrong with your CSS.  Have you run it through a validator to check to see if there are no syntax errors?  Are the rules within a media query that isn't in effect?

Comment: I used the dev tools and noticed what was overriding and why the colour of the text was merging it into the same colour of the footer. Thanks Jim.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/GgdhX/

You're using a lot of descendant selectors for IDs and needless classes on `LI` elements.

```
#foot-nav .blah{
   list-style-type: none;
 }

#foot-nav .blah li{
    padding:2px 0;  
 }

#foot-nav .blah li a{
    color:#333;
    text-decoration: none;
 }

#foot-nav .blah a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

<div id="foot-nav">
    <ul class="blah">
        <li><a href="">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">site map</a></li>
        <li>three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How come you've removed ul from the css?

Comment: Scope of question changed through several modifications, my answer is not likely relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all the `#footer` aspects of the selectors you have on there, everything should work perfectly. I made a [jsfiddle of the working copy](http://jsfiddle.net/f78U8/). Let me know if this is the UI concept you had in mind. Also, I suggest you read up on [CSS Specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) to understand how rules are prioritized when applied to different nested elements